# Container with content, that can slide

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I got an idea, but I got no idea on how to make it.
Okay, so here is the deal.

I want a container which can contain certain objects (These objects will draw the sprites/graphics).
But because of different screen sizes, I want to be able to scale the containers width and height. But I do not want the objects in the container, that go outside of the container, because of the scaling to be visible.

Because I want the objects all to be positioned horizontally to each other and I want a horizontal slider bar, so I can slide from left to right within the container.

I wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I am sorry for that. I just try to be nice ;)

Comment: You could use a [`RenderTarget2D`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/26/rendertarget-changes-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) to draw the items in the container to a texture that's the size of the container itself, then draw that texture inside the container. You offset the drawing to the RenderTarget2D based on the horizontal scroll value.

Comment: @DijkeMark: no problem. Just keep in mind this isn't a discussion forum. We're not having a conversation.

Comment: Also, you could use a [ScissorRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.scissorrectangle.aspx) and [ScissorTestEnable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rasterizerstate.scissortestenable.aspx) to define the area in which to draw the container content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using ScissorRectangle and ScissorTestEnable, just as Niko said.
Thanks!